# Infinite set notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

> Is it acceptable to write "$X$ is an infinite set" as "$|X| = \infty$"?

By "acceptable" I mean that I can use it in a research paper or in a textbook, and a reasonable person won't be against it. Possible arguments against it:

1. $\infty$ is not actually a value, so it doesn't fit into a standard set-size notation.
2. $|\mathbb R| = \infty$ and $|\mathbb N| = \infty$, so one may think that $|\mathbb R| = |\mathbb N|$.

(I looked for duplicates with some variations of the title, and found none)

Comment: I would strongly recommend against it. Either write it in words, or write $|X|\ge\aleph_0$, $|X|\ge\omega$, or the like.

Comment: While I haven't published any papers or books, I would think it depends on the context. If you're writing about, say, set theory, where precise cardinalities are often a subject of study, using this notation would be very jarring. But, if you're writing about some field where this sort of question doesn't come up, I wouldn't have a problem with it.

Comment: "$X$ is an infinite set" is unambiguous. Your other option raises questions ("What does "$|\cdot$|" mean for an arbitrary set?" for one.)  Why raise unnecessary questions?

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC "$\vert\cdot\vert$" is meaningful for arbitrary sets, I don't think that's an issue here.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: As someone who does more more analysis and topology than set theory, I know what it means for two sets to be the same size, but I couldn't tell you if $| \cdot |$ (for arbitrary sets) is a function or not, and if it is I don't know what its co-domain is. Or maybe it's a family of functions, defined along some hierarchy of sets. Regardless, if that's not the subject under study I'd just as well not have to worry about it, and this question is tagged "elementary set theory".

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC By definition "$\vert A\vert$" is the smallest ordinal in bijection with $A$. If we want to think of $\vert\cdot\vert$ as a function-like thing, it's an example of a **class function**: technically not a function but rather a *formula* with two free variables $\varphi(x,y)$ such that $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves "For all $x$ there is exactly one $y$ with $\varphi(x,y)$" (or "Every set has a unique cardinality"); in this context its domain and codomain are each $V$, the universe of all sets. *(That said, if we drop choice there is a more technical definition of cardinality.)*

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I do like to hear about such details (and "some hierarchy of sets" was my brain trying to recover dim scraps of having seen $V$ before), but that still strikes me as an awful lot of machinery just to say that a set is not finite. Kind of like describing how to implement the free group on $n$ generators when all you're going to use is $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\infty$ is a bit ambiguous/misplaced in the context of set cardinality, something like an Aleph Number (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_number) might be more appropriate, i.e. $|X| \ge \aleph_0$, which states "X has the cardinality of at least the smallest possible infinite set".

Comment: I consider myself reasonable  :-), and I'm going to say "Don't do this". If all you really want to do is distinguish finite from infinite, then all you'll do with  the $|X| \ge \aleph_0$ notation is show that you've taken some set theory. My guideline is "If you're not going to use $\aleph_1$, then why mention $\aleph_0$?".

Answer (score 2):

I'm personally strongly against this - we have more exact notation for describing infinite sets, so why not use it?

That said, I have seen this notation used when describing objects which are subsets of some fixed countable set (e.g. sets of natural numbers). Here there's really no possible confusion. However, I still consider this bad practice.